# Using scrapy to find the right data in tables

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to get text on a website that has many tables. Eventually I want to make it to where it does multiple pages of the same layout. The problem is the xpath of the tables can change. Where the xpath might be `table 3, row 4` on one page, on a different one it could be `table 2, row 5` for the information I need. How do I write an xpath where it chooses the table if it contains a certain text, then the row if it contains a certain text, then finally the end text.

For example:

The html snippet would look like:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                <b>Table Blah</b>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th width="133" id="sub">
                <p align="right">
                    <b>Row Blah</b>
                </p>
            </th>
            <td>Get Me!</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Where if the `<thead>` contains the text `Table Blah`, and the `<tr>` in `<tbody>` contains the text `Row Blah` then grab the text `Get Me!` within `Row Blah`'s `<tr>`

Comment: why scapy ? why not requests or selenium with beautiful soup 4 ? Use the right tool for the job

Comment: @lxx according to the description, `Scrapy` **is** the right tool here. It doesn't mean `bs4` or `selenium` don't fit though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a *single XPath expression* and reach the `Get me!`:

```
//table[contains(thead/tr/th/b, 'Table Blah')]/tbody/tr[contains(th/p/b, 'Row Blah')]/td/text()
```

Demo from the [shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) (`index.html` contains the same data from the question):

```
$ scrapy shell index.html
In [1]: response.xpath("//table[contains(thead/tr/th/b, 'Table Blah')]/tbody/tr[contains(th/p/b, 'Row Blah')]/td/text())").extract()
Out[1]: [u'Get Me!']
```

Answer (score 1):

> "Where if the `<thead>` contains the text `Table Blah`, and the `<tr>` in `<tbody>` contains the text `Row Blah` then grab the text `Get Me!` within `Row Blah`'s `<tr>`"

Translating above descriptions into XPath (formatted for readability) :

```
//table[contains(thead,'Table Blah')]
/tbody
/tr[contains(th,'Row Blah')]
/td
```